Issues with VM crashing when migrating to a specific host
We have had a long standing issues in our environment where when sometimes a virtual machine migrates to a specific host in the cluster, the VM becomes hung and is no longer available. When it happens the symptoms identified are;
•   The VM displays no DNS Name when clicking on it in the inventory
•   The VM displays no IP information when clicking on it in the inventory
•   You can no longer ping the VM
•   The VM preview window shows a black screen and when you click to launch web console it just loads a black window
•   VMWare tools at the top becomes 'unavailable for use'
Image of vcenter when VM crashes
This happens until the VM is rebooted and it all comes back on, we have 8 ESXi hosts in the cluster all running hypervisor version 7.0.3, build 23307199. This can also happen with any flavour of Linux and happens on all versions of Windows Server (2012, 2016 and 2019).
This can occur in the following scenarios;
•   When a VM migrates from any of the other 7 ESXi hosts to this specific one
•   When the VM has been sat on this ESXi host for a while it randomly just crashes
Troubleshooting tried
•   We have had the host rebuilt which did not resolve the problem
•   We have had lenovo check the host over for any physical problems and have come up with nothing
It’s almost like VMWare tools crash on the VM when moving to a certain host, but I really can’t understand why or how!
Any insight or ideas would be greatly appreciated!
